# At least two circuits disconnect intermittantly. Breaker does not trip. Voltage measures low sometimes

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, low-voltage

I noticed two that two circuits cut off intermittanly but circuit breaker did not trip. I tested voltage with meter when the the problem was happening and found about five volts on both the incoming and outgoing side of every other breaker. I also tested the two wires coming into and out of the main breaker. One of the main wires going to the main breaker also showed about 5 volts when the problem was happening (tested the main wire before the breaker and coming out of the breaker both showed about 5 volts). When the problem is not happening all wires and breakers show about 115 volts. Does the fact the the voltage of one of the two main hot wiress showed 5 volts before it went into the Main breaker mean that the problem is befire my electric box and therefore the responsibility of the electric company?

UPDATE: Power company came out and said there was a bad connector on the roof. I am assuming it was where the wire from the pole connects to the wire coming into the meter and house. Thanks everyone.

Comment: If the problem was with the electric company side, it would affect at least half your circuits, rather than just two.

Comment: Probably 70% plus chance it is power company problem, especially if you have overhead lines to the house.  The rest could be between the meter and main panel.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  OP probably only tested the two circuits/outlets that gave them problems, not the whole house.  OP also stated one main was low also.

Comment: Do you have an electric water heater, 240V A/C unit, or other 240V load which operates cyclically automatically?  Or, does the problem seem to fix itself when you turn on a 240V load like range or dryer?

Answer (score 1):

Only 5 volts from and incoming power line?   Call the electric company now.

Comment: Ecnerwal - it does affect half the circuits when I measured the voltage. Every other breaker has low voltage.

Comment: RMDman - Thank you for your response. Yes 5 volts intermittantly. Sometimes 115 volts sometimes 5 volts.

Comment: crip659- to clarify I tested all circuit breakers with meter half were 5 volts when the problem was happeneing. Alternating breakers had low voltage.

Comment: @LeeNaqvi yeah, that's a dead hot leg, call your power company and tell them you have a partial power outage -- they'll need to roll a truck to fix this.